# Removing a object from array state ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a functional component, in that i have a array state with object as items.
now i wanted to remove an item at particular position.

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    { project: "aaaa", task: "xxxxx", status: true },
    { project: "bbbb", task: "yyyyz", status: true },
    { project: "cccc", task: "zzzzz", status: true }

  ]);

  function addTask(task) {
    setTasks(oldArray => [...oldArray, task]);
  }

  function deleteTask(pos) {
    let _tasks = tasks;
    _tasks.splice(pos, 1);
    setTasks(_tasks)
  }
```

here the task is get deleted but UI is not updated untill i add a new item to state array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't create a copy of your state variable `let _tasks = tasks;`, merely a reference. So by doing that you're mutating the state variable directly. You could remove an element at a given position by simply doing this:

```
  function deleteTask(pos) {
    setTasks(oldArray => oldArray.filter((item, index) => index !== pos));
  }
```

This assumes that `pos` is an integer representing the index of the element you want to remove